# Still have the P0401 code despite replacing EGR valve twice

Tags: honda, accord, p0401

I have a 200 honda accord with 275K miles on it. I have replace two EGR valves in the last 4 months. The problem I have is after 15 minutes of driving, the car will stall and I have to wait about a minute and it will start back up. and then 2 minutes later it happens again. I can't believe I had two faulty EGR values installed.

Comment: What do you mean by "EGR Values"? And what is your question here?

Comment: The model year is unspecified

Answer (score 1):

Remember that <kbd>P0401</kbd> indicates the symptom, not the root cause.

Carbon build-up along the exhaust gas recirculation line is quite common (and easy enough to clean out), so something as simple as a clogged EGR pipe could explain what's going on here.

You could replace a thousand EGR valves but if there is something else in the EGR loop that is restricting flow it won't do squat to solve the issue.